# Writing AIR native extension for Android

Tags: android, air, air-native-extension

I am writing a native extension that needs to setup a map, dynamically add/remove Markers, adjust camera/zoom, etc from a mobile air project.  I have created a test project and built an ane file with the `FREFunctions` supporting the functionality needed.  However it is not clear where I go from here.  Here are my questions:

1. Should I create an Android Activity for each `FREFunction` class, or have each `FREFunction` also be a Activity?
2. Do I need to define all Activities, Services, etc in the  AIR project's app descriptor, under Android (manifestAdditions) , or just define them in the Android Project's manifest file?
3. I created a map in the first/launcher activity, and am successfully calling it. However I am failing to call any subsequent Activities due to permission issues.  THis makes me think I might be doing things wrong.  Should I create a wrapper Service around the map, and call the service from my `FREFunctions`, instead of trying to setup multiple Activities?  So the first Activity would start the service and then from that point on, I would be calling the Service.  Is that better?

Comment: Hi @Patrick. Did you find answers to your questions ? An answer to question 2 would be great :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. FREFunction classes should not be activities, they are classes that implement the FREFunction interface.
2. Any activities, receivers etc that you need the system to know about must be defined in the manifest file, however this doesn't mean all of them. Generally you only need to define activities and receivers that may be launched by the system when the application isn't in the foreground. You can add an activity and have it started from your native code without having it in the manifest. Additionally anything you put in the Android Library Project manifest file is NOT used.
3. Check that you've added the correct permissions to your manifest additions. And yes you'd be better off starting one activity from your FREFunction that handles all of the functionality you require.

Hope that helps